# How to solve cannot assign to function call in python?

Tags: python, random, syntax-error

I am supposed to write function `randomWorld`. It takes in two integers width and height which represent the width and height of the world and returns a dict that represents the world. I have been following the teacher algorithm idea but I am getting this

> SyntaxError cannot assign to function call

and this is what I have done

```
def randomWorld(width, height):
    """Return a random world"""
    world={}
    for x in range(width):        
      for y in range(height):
        if random.randint(0,10) < 3:
         world.Cell(x,y)=True
    return world
```

Comment: What is `world.Cell` supposed to be, and why are you trying to assign to `world.Cell(x,y)`?

Comment: You initialized `world` to a dict. Those don't have a `Cell` method. Even if they did, you can't assign to a method call.

Comment: I have no clue actually these are the instructions I have 1.Create an empty dict"world = {}".
2.For all x in range (width) and for all y in range (height), if random.randint (0.10) <3 set Cell (x, y) to True in world.
3.Return world

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want:

```
world[x,y] = True
```